# Using Access Next Record to Cycle through records that have a certain field as null

Tags: database, ms-access, validationrules

So I'm running into trouble, I'm trying to use Next and Previous record buttons (using prebuilt macros) to cycle through the ID of different resources. However, I'd like it to go through ONLY the Records where "TimeReturned" in Table "Loans" is empty (null).

I've tried using validation rules on the specific Textbox; here's what I tried (with no success): `[Loans]![TimeReturned] Is Null`

Should I even by trying to use the Validation Rules to achieve this?

Thanks!

EDIT:
I think I should be changing the Macro I'm using to cycle through the entries rather than just the text field for the ID. >.<

Comment: What you really should do is filter the recordset you are using so that it only returns records with null values. I assume you have a form bound to some table or query?

Comment: Yes. The current form is bound to table "Loans" as mentioned above.

Comment: So is there any reason you can't base it on a query that only selects the null records?

Comment: Alright, I was able to get it working using RecordSet. Just had to figure out what access feature I was suppose to use to achieve what I wanted. If you want to post this as an answer, I'll mark it as the answer. :) Thanks!

Comment: No, that's ok. But am curious if / how you are filtering. Your macro could have been designed to 'loop until null', or you could add a form filter.

Comment: I switched back to using a Query (was using a Table) for the form and set this in my Query filters. http://puu.sh/g4jNs/145e8c58dc.png However, I'd like the arrows to Next Record and Previews Record to cycle and stop it from going to (New) at the very end of the list (if possible)

Comment: Set the form property 'Allow Additions' to No.